# Django Rest API ManyToMany gives nothing [] in API

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

at the moment I try to get recipes from my API. I have a Database with two tables one is with recipes and their ids but without the ingredients, the other table contains the ingredients and also the recipe id. Now I cant find a way that the API "combines" those. Maybe its because I added in my ingredient model to the  recipe id the related name, but I had to do this because otherwise, this error occurred:

```
ERRORS:
recipes.Ingredients.recipeid: (fields.E303) Reverse query name for 'Ingredients.recipeid' clashes with field name 'Recipe.ingredients'.
        HINT: Rename field 'Recipe.ingredients', or add/change a related_name argument to the definition for field 'Ingredients.recipeid'.
```

### Models

```
from django.db import models

class Ingredients(models.Model):
    ingredientid = models.AutoField(db_column='IngredientID', primary_key=True, blank=True)
    recipeid = models.ForeignKey('Recipe', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='recipeid', blank=True, null=True, related_name='+')
    amount = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=100)
    unit = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=100)
    unit2 = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=100)
    ingredient = models.CharField(db_column='Ingredient', blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)
    
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'Ingredients'  

class Recipe(models.Model):
    recipeid = models.AutoField(db_column='RecipeID', primary_key=True, blank=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    title = models.CharField(db_column='Title', blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)  # Field name made lowercase.
    preperation = models.TextField(db_column='Preperation', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    images = models.CharField(db_column='Images', blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)  # Field name made lowercase.
    #ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredients) 
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredients, related_name='recipes')
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'Recipes'
```

When there is no issue it has to be in the serializer or in the view.

### Serializer

```
class IngredientsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   # ingredients = serializers.CharField(source='ingredients__ingredients')

    class Meta:
        model = Ingredients
        fields = ['ingredient','recipeid']

class FullRecipeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    ingredients = IngredientsSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = ['title','ingredients']
```

### View

```
class FullRecipesView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = FullRecipeSerializer
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.AllowAny
    ]
    queryset = Recipe.objects.all()
```

[This is at the moment my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Kalo.jpg)
But I want e.g. the recipe with id 0 and all the ingredients which have also recipe id 0.
I really hope that you can help me. Thank you so much!

Comment: Are you getting any error or something?

Comment: A couple of things: You could have followed the hint rather than doing whatever you think is the right thing to do. Review Django documentation if you don't understand the hint. Secondly, you have your Recipe model marked as managed and your Ingredients model is not managed. Is that intentional? I'm assuming that they are both un-managed which begs the question of why are using Django? Finally, to answer your question about JSON serializability, check the Django Rest Framework [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/) for that.

Comment: @Bobort I read the documentation multiple times but the documentation just has an example of the many to many with a database they are filling. My database is already filled and I look for a way to "combine" the data.

Comment: And at the moment I don't know where the issue is and I just want to know if it is something in the model or in the API itself and because of this, I tried changing different values where I was not 100% sure if they were right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the doc of [**`ForeignKey.related_name`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name),

> If you’d prefer Django not to create a backwards relation, set `related_name` to `'+'` or end it with `'+'`.

So, change the `related_name` of **`Ingredients.recipeid`** field to

```
class Ingredients(models.Model):
    # rest of the fields
    recipeid = models.ForeignKey(
        'Recipe',
        models.DO_NOTHING,
        db_column='recipeid',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name="ingredients_ref" # Changed the related name 
    )
```

Then, migrate the database using `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`

Then, update your **`FullRecipeSerializer`** class as,

```
class FullRecipeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ingredients_forward = IngredientsSerializer(many=True, source="ingredients")
    ingredients_backward = IngredientsSerializer(many=True, source="ingredients_ref")

    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = ['title', 'ingredients_forward', 'ingredients_backward']
```

Note that, here I have added two fields named `ingredients_forward` and `ingredients_backward` because there existing two types of relationships between `Recipe` and `Ingredients` and I am not sure which one you are seeking.

Comment: Thank you it works. But do I understand it right that I need ingredients backward to get the ingredients from the recipe? And how can I use ingredient forward?

Comment: ***as per your model structure*** both are different in your case. I am wondering why you need the `Ingredients.recipeid` in the first-place

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I need the recipe id because its the only reference to the recipe

Comment: Okay, then what is the issue now?

Comment: I just want to understand what ingredients forward and backward is for.